# hyperref command doesn't point to the right place in beamer

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I write some equations in the beamer and I want to point to these equations by using the hyperlink, but the link produced by the command `hyperref[label]{text}` in package `hyperref` doesn't point to the right place while the `\ref` command points to the right place. For example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=red,
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[c]\frametitle{page 1}
        \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
            123
        \end{equation}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[c]\frametitle{page 2}
        \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
            456
        \end{equation}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[c]\frametitle{page 3}
    Right link, will point to page 2:\ref{eq:2}\par
    Wrong link, doesn't point to page 2:\hyperref[eq:2]{The equation 2}\par
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I use `xelatex` as the compiler and the platform is TL2016 and windows 7.

Comment: Apparently `beamer` does provide link anchors other than 'usual' classes and packages. Replace `\hyperref[eq:2]{The equation 2}` with `\hyperlink{eq:2}{The equation 2}` and it will work inside `beamer`, but it wouldn't work inside a document setup with aother document class. Besides that, there's not much to gain with `\hyperref` here what could not be done with `\ref` already

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `\hyperref[]{}` use `\hyperlink{}{}` -- `\hyperlink` is redefined in `beamer` to use the usual `\ref` internally, since that command uses links by default (with `hyperref`) and the link will work,but it would fail in another document set up with another document class since `\hyperlink` applies the anchor name and not the label name.

Also note that `\hyperlink` does support the slide overlay `<>` syntax in `beamer` as well.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor=red,
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[c]\frametitle{page 1}
        \begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
            123
        \end{equation}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[c]\frametitle{page 2}
        \begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
            456
        \end{equation}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[c]\frametitle{page 3}
    Right link, will point to page 2:\ref{eq:2}

    Correct link, does point to page 2:\hyperlink{eq:2}{The equation 2} as well!
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```